Module / Class Call in a list?
I'm trying to put someting like tk.CTkEntry(master=self, placeholder_text="Amount") in a list (or anything alse). I think I tried every "list like" option.
Any Ideas how to do that ?
It schould be someting like:
button[1] = tk.CTkEntry(master=self, placeholder_text="Amount")

What are you trying to do exactly? button[1] = tk.CTkEntry(master=self, placeholder_text="Amount") should work, assuming button is a list. Please try to include a [mre] in the body of your question.

button.append(tk.CTkEntry(...)) to add the button to the list.

Using .append() completely solved the problem. Thank you.
